# Updating boot2docker to 1.4.0 not taking

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to update docker/boot2docker using boot2docker download command but upon starting it, it  is still running 1.3.2 client (docker --version)

```
  bash-3.2$ boot2docker download
  Latest release for boot2docker/boot2docker is v1.4.0
  Downloading boot2docker ISO image...
   Success: downloaded https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.4.0/boot2docker.iso
```

Also, from the docker github OS X installer page, 1.3.2 is the only download option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually download latest Docker binary and replace the existing one. Instruction [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/).

This is my shell script to install+update latest Docker on a CentOS6/RHEL:

```
#!/bin/bash

# YUM install docker with required dependencies
yum -y install docker-io

# Move to a temp working directory
work_dir=$(mktemp -d)
cd "${work_dir}"
trap "rm -rf -- ${work_dir}" EXIT

# WGET latest release of Docker
wget https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest -O docker
chmod +x docker

# Replaces Docker with latest Docker binary
mv docker /usr/bin/docker

# Start Docker service
service docker start
```

Depend on where your binaries are stored, it might be a different location than */usr/bin*